# Haskell Platform installation on Ubuntu 13.04 detects wrong version of ghc

Tags: ubuntu, haskell

I am trying to install haskell on my ubuntu 13.04

I am following this article

https://askubuntu.com/questions/286764/how-to-install-haskell-platform-for-ubuntu-13-04

I installed ghc first by

```
sudo apt-get install ghc
```

Then I download the ghc 7.6.3 source code and successfully did the make and make install

```
wget http://www.haskell.org/ghc/dist/7.6.3/ghc-7.6.3-src.tar.bz2
tar xjvf ghc-7.6.3-src.tar.bz2
cd ghc-7.6.3
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Now when I do

```
wget http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/download/2013.2.0.0/haskell-platform-2013.2.0.0.tar.gz
tar xzvf haskell-platform-2013.2.0.0.tar.gz
cd haskell-platform-2013.2.0.0.tar.gz
./configure
```

I get an error

```
checking for hsc2hs... /usr/bin/hsc2hs
checking version of ghc... ****7.6.2****
configure: error: The Haskell Platform version 2013.2.0.0 requires ghc-7.6.3
  It is recommended that you upgrade to ghc-7.6.3 however if you
  really want to use this release with an unsupported version of GHC
  then use ./configure --enable-unsupported-ghc-version
  abhishek@sp2013vm16:~/haskell-platform-2013.2.0.0$
```

Why does it say that my ghc is 7.6.2?? I have done the sudo make install for ghc 7.6.3

Comment: Even when I run ghci it says

GHCi, version 7.6.2:

But you see that above I did a make install on 7.6.3

Comment: I did this some time ago, and I don't remeber the details that well, but isn't it necessary to add the binary created by make install to your path?

Comment: I know I'm a bit late to the game, but "make install" usually installs executables to /usr/local/bin and that's not on your default path.